# what's the risk of closing socket which is used in another thread by accept?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, sockets

I have a server application.

The server is accpting the connection from clients in a thread with:

```
 while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
{
     .....
 }
```

I have another thread which executed in the exit of my application. in this thread I close the socket `socket_desc`:

```
close(socket_desc);
```

what is the risk of closing a socket in a thread and there is another thread wich make accept on the same socket?

Comment: You should always synchronize access to shared data when using threads - is there any reason why you'd consider `socket_desc` here to be an exception to that?

Comment: OT: This `(socklen_t*)&c` does not look nice. Declare `c` to be of `socklen_t` and this dangerous pointer casting would not be necessary.

Comment: And indeed, error checking the call to `accept()` is fully missing as it returns `-1` on failure. All values `>=0` are valid.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong. But, it might be for a scenario like this:- Consider 3 threads - A, B, C.

1. Thread A waits on socket and goes to sleep
2. Thread B closes the socket
3. Thread C creates a new socket and which happens to get the same file descriptor number as the recently closed socket ( Socket is also a file )
4. Thread A wakes up ( with error code on `accept` ) and then call
   `close` thinking unexpected error => This affects a completely different valid socket created in C !!

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the semantics of the combination of actions you describe are not defined, and that should be enough of a concern to find an alternative.  I *speculate* that behaviors reasonably likely to be observed include

- the `close()` returning quickly, and

  - the `accept()` call failing quickly, perhaps indicating an `EBADF`, `EINVAL`, or `ENOTSOCK` error, or
  - the `accept()` call continuing to block until a connection request arrives, or
  - the `accept()` call blocking indefinitely; or
- the `close()` blocking until `accept()` returns, if it ever does; or
- `close()` and `accept()` deadlocking.

If indeed the semantics are not defined, however, then pretty much anything could happen.

If a different thread must close the socket than the one `accept()`ing connections on it, then you would be wise to set some sort of flag to indicate that the program is exiting, then `signal()` the `accept()`ing thread to break it out of `accept()`.  The thread(s) receiving such a signal would know from the program-exiting flag to stop instead of trying to `accept()` again.

If your threads are cancelable, then the global flag could take the form of a thread-cancellation message.  The `accept()` function is a cancellation point, so your threads will receive the cancellation message no later than the next time they call `accept()`.

Comment: Your approach with a flag to be tested before the `accept` call can't work because you can't predict, when the thread switch will occur. If it occurs after reading of the flag and before diving into the internals of `accept` then you have the same Problem as w/o the flag.

Comment: Easier might be to call `select()` instead of `accept()`, and have the exiting thread write to a pipe that `select()` is waiting on, so the server thread can handle the `close()` to avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: @harper, Naturally, if you implement the flag as a variable, you must appropriately synchronize access to it.  But if you set the flag before `signal()`ing the threads to break them out of `accept()`, as described, then you can be sure they will see the flag when they loop back around.  (I.e. the variable must be tested both before and in the loop body.)  If you implement the flag via thread cancelation then you don't even need to mess with explicit synchronization.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, having the server threads block on `select()` instead of on `accept()` would provide a *cleaner* way to interrupt the server threads than signalling them would do.  It's a solid approach, and I hadn't considered it.  I'm not convinced that it would actually be *easier* to implement, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the socket to abort the accept function. But you must change the code, and check the return value of API functions carefully. Your attempt while the while loop will not work, since it doesn't check for SOCK_ERROR (-1).

Comment: Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: Careful, @harper: Firstly, Linux is not MS Windows, and the socket APIs are different between the two! One of the differences is this constant you mention, `SOCK_ERROR`, which only exists in the WinSock API. That said, I know that simply closing the socket works at least on win32, but it's questionable if that also applies to POSIX systems.